# month wise collection in mongodb using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a simple demo using mongodb mongoose.but my issue is I want to create `month wise collection` example `SEP_2019` ,`OCT_2019`,`DEC_2019`.but **each collection schema is same**

```
var personSchema = new Schema({
 name: String
});
```

I have only one `attribute/field name` in my schema.

so my collection have this type of data

```
`SEP_2019`
[{
name:'test'
}]
```

so I want to create **collection dynamically on the base of the month** insert my data in that collection also `retrieve` that data from collection.also query that on collection ?

will I use `mongoos` or `mongo client`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mongoose, the collection name is defined when you create a model from your schema.

You'd do something like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var personSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});

const Sep2019 = mongoose.model('SEP_2019', personSchema)

let newPerson = Sep2019.create({name: 'test'});
```

Comment: thanks for answer ..!! `SEP_2019 ` is dynamic .it means it depend on current month .

Comment: Yes, you have to create that string and pass it to mongoose.model().  I assume you do that already.

Comment: let take example i create a `webservice` on insert data .so the current month is `DEC` so I want the collection i created ` name of `DEC_2019` . each request come on that month only save data in `DEC_2019` collection

Comment: `const Sep2019 = mongoose.model('SEP_2019', personSchema)
` what happen if `SEP_2019` already created ? if some insert data again

Comment: If the collection is already there, mongoose.model() will refer to the existing one, and you can create/read/update/delete documents in it.

Comment: so you are saying in `app.get('/saveData',()=>{var model =mongoose.model('DYNAMIC_NAME', personSchema) });
model.save();
model.findByID()

`these function work ?? correct ?

Comment: Yup.  ```mongoose.model()``` ensures your table exists, then you can use it like any model/collection.

Comment: FYI, there are other ways to segregate data in a collection, so without knowing what you're trying to accomplish, I can't say this is the most efficient approach, but this is how you would accomplish what you are asking for.

Comment: thanks .so again i will explain my problem.example I want to store `name or attendence` of all person which are working in my company ..!! example `30000` person in my company .if I take only one collection `30000*30` (30 is the day in month) these documents create in each month

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199342/discussion-between-jim-b-and-user944513).

Comment: `30000*30*12` will generate more documents in same collection